# .net - dictionary.Keys.Add?

Tags: .net, dictionary, ienumerable, icollection

In .Net, `IDictionary<K, V>` defines `.Keys` and `.Values` properties, each of which is an `ICollection<>` rather than `IEnumerable<>`, which seems like it would be a more natural fit to me.

Is there any reasonable use case to call `.Add` or `.Remove` on `.Keys` or `.Values` of an instance of an `IDictionary<K, V>`?

Comment: What are you thinking it would mean to add something to `Keys` rather than the dictionary itself?

Comment: One thing that `ICollection<>` supplies is a `Count` property. `IEnumerable<>` has a `Count()` method. Also, it's likely that if you get the value of `IsReadOnly` (again, defined by `ICollection<>`), you'll find that it's `False`, meaning that you can't modify the collection.

Comment: @JimMischel: I believe you meant to say, "if you get the value of `IsReadOnly` (again, defined by `ICollection<>`), you'll find that it's **`True`**, meaning that you can't modify the collection" and that is certainly the case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, probably no reasonable use case. There are very few (probably zero) legitimate reasons for this at all.

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class returns a `KeyCollection` for its `.Keys` which in turn throws `NotSupportedException` with **"Mutating a key collection derived from a dictionary is not allowed."** whenever trying to add directly to it. I imagine that it returns an `ICollection` for legacy reasons and probably should be avoided at all costs now.

In fact unless the `ICollection` returned from `.Keys` had a reference to its containing `IDictionary`, I can't see anything useful happen. The `.Add` of the `ICollection` would have to tell the containing `IDictionary` what this add meant. Perhaps you wanted to implement some form of a `Set` you could do something like this:

```
public class StringSet : IDictionary<string, int> {
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _InternalDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public int this[string key] {
        get { return _InternalDictionary[key]; }
        set { _InternalDictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    private StringCollection _Keys;
    public ICollection<string> Keys {
        get {
            if(_Keys == null) _Keys = new StringCollection(this);
            return _Keys;
        }
    }
    ICollection<string> IDictionary<string, int>.Keys {
        get {
            if(_Keys == null) _Keys = new StringCollection(this);
            return _Keys;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<int> Values { get { throw new NotImplementedException();} }

    public void Add(string key, int value) { _InternalDictionary.Add(key, value); }
    public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return _InternalDictionary.ContainsKey(key); }
    public bool Remove(string key) { return _InternalDictionary.Remove(key); }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out int value) { return _InternalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value); }
    public void Clear() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, int> item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, int> item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, int>[] array, int arrayIndex) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, int> item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public int Count { get { return _InternalDictionary.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}

public class StringCollection : ICollection<string> {
    private readonly StringSet _ContainingSet;
    public StringCollection(StringSet set) {
        _ContainingSet = set;
    }

    public void Add(string item) {
        if(_ContainingSet.ContainsKey(item)) _ContainingSet[item]++;
        else _ContainingSet[item] = 1;
    }

    public bool Contains(string item) { return _ContainingSet.ContainsKey(item); }
    public bool Remove(string item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void Clear() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public int Count { get { return _ContainingSet.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

Surely there is a better way to implement this or similar for your specific needs. The only benefit this has is allowing `.Add` on the returned `Keys` `StringCollection`. I would want to force people using my `StringSet` to use the parent `StringSet` class anyway. But, it is possible that someone would want the above overridden behavior.

Call it with this:

```
var set = new StringSet();
var keys = set.Keys;
keys.Add("hello");
keys.Add("hello");
keys.Add("world");
Debug.Print("hello: {0}, world: {1}", set["hello"], set["world"]);
```

Comment: I would expect that the `KeyCollection` would hold a reference to a dictionary, and serve mainly to forward accesses to `GetEnumerator` and `Count` (the `ICollection` interface existing to provide the latter).

Comment: @supercat: Yep, `Dictionary.KeyCollection` and `Dictionary.ValueCollection` just hold a reference to the `Dictionary` and use it for basically just forwarding the properties and methods they do implement, `Count`, `Contains(TValue item)`, `GetEnumerator()`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reasonable use case for calling `Add` or `Remove` on the key or value collections. What would you expect the resulting dictionary to look like?

I'm pretty sure that all of the framework's built-in implementations of `IDictionary<K,V>` will throw a `NotSupportedException`, or similar, if you try to do it. (And you should probably do the same thing in any of your own implementations too.)